# Mchess exception

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying CHESS to help me to avoid some race conditions that I have in a program.
I would like to try mchess with the BankAccount example, but I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Research\CHESS\Resources\Samples\Managed\BankAccount>ChessTest.exe
True

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Research\CHESS\Resources\Samples\Managed\BankAccount>mchess ChessTest.exe
ManagedCHESS. Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation, 2008.
Analyzing ChessTest.exe  ...

Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Research\CHESS\Resources\Samples\Managed\BankAccount>
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks,
Stenio

Comment: Chess is not a supported Microsoft product.  It is open sourced and moved to where Microsoft code [goes to die](http://chesstool.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/69631).  Which does give you the option to debug and fix whatever problem is ailing it.  Don't discount the possibility that the SO bug is in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved in a later version. There is no binary download anyway.

[Source code link](http://chesstool.codeplex.com/SourceControl/BrowseLatest)

Regards,
Stenio